# PHP saving multidimensional array in session

Tags: php, session

```
<?php
session_start();

$_SESSION[] = array('itemName'=> "'".$_POST["name"]."'",
                    'itemPrice'=> "'".$_POST["price"]."'"
                    );
print_r($_SESSION);
?>
```

I am posting the data through jQuery, and although the `print_r` displays correct data, but PHP above doesn't save in session, any idea?

Comment: put a name inside the brackets of $_SESSION-variable?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You will have to give some kind of index/key (name) to the session-variable, so PHP know how to refer to it.

Here's how **$_SESSION['test']** is assigned:

```
$_SESSION['test'] = array('itemName'=> "'".$_POST["name"]."'",
                        'itemPrice'=> "'".$_POST["price"]."'"
                        );
```

Answer (score 2):

You have to use `$_SESSION['name']` to store to session, not just `$_SESSION[]`

```
<?php
session_start();

$_SESSION['name'] = array('itemName'=> "'".$_POST["name"]."'",
                    'itemPrice'=> "'".$_POST["price"]."'"
                    );
print_r($_SESSION);
?>
```